# NSDateFormatter decrease the date by one hour always

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-05-24T10:30:00+0200";
        NSLog(@"date string before format %@", dateString);
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"date string after format %@", dateString);
```

And the output is :

```
date string before format 2013-05-24T10:30:00+0200
date string after format 2013-05-24T09:30:00+0100
```

Why does it show 10:30 then 9:30 ?!!!

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: 2013-05-24T10:30:00+0200 is the same as 2013-05-24T09:30:00+0100, just different timezones. The +0200 and +0100 is the timezone

Answer (score 2):

Timezone will be causing the trouble

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: I tried both and it's worse :( 
now it decreases by 2 hours:
date string before format 2013-05-24T10:30:00+0200
date string after format 2013-05-24T08:30:00+0100

Answer (score 2):

The result is OK. Both dates are the same, just after parsing the string to `NSDate`, `NSLog` prints you output with your local zone.

See: you have `10:30 + 2h` in string and `9:30 + 1h` timezone offset in parsed date. It means both dates are `8:30 GMT`

**Edit for clarification:**

`NSDate` is date representation independent on timezone. So internal representation of parsed `NSDate` instance correctly describes date in your input string and you can safely use the date for calculations etc. It just depends how the final string is created by `NSDateFormatter`. It creates the string in your local time zone by default. That's why your output is not exactly the same string as input. But if you calculate hours + timezone offset, it's correct.

If you really need to have have same output string, you must explicitly set the `NSDateFormatter`s time zone or `NSLocale` to the same timezone as the input date string has (some locale / timezone with timezone offset +2 from `GMT`)

Comment: I'm printing a string here whith NSLog() not dates

Comment: That doesn't matter. You are printing string which you constructed using `NSDateFormatter`. But the date formatter gives you output in your local timezone by default. So until you explicitly set some `NSLocale` to the output date formatter, you will get result in local timezone.

Comment: Emm you're right,
I had to remove the time zone characters from the string date ("+0200") by using [NSString substringToIndex:19] and then use this date formatter "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The time is the same, it's just a different timezone, just set the timezone of you date:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```